# How do you dynamically add a method to an existing object when the method you want to add uses the "super" keyword in its body?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope, metaprogramming, prototype-chain

Suppose you want to add a method `f()` to an object `myObj` where `f()` uses the `super` keyword in its body. Eg:

```
function f() {
    return super.foo() + 10
}

myObj.foo = f
```

Well, this doesn't work, because `f()` can't be declared (since `super` isn't bound to anything).

Is there a way to dynamically add a method to an object when the method uses the `super` keyword in the method body?

Comment: Maybe: [Using super.prop in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#using_super.prop_in_object_literals)

Comment: The linked page talks about using "super" in object literals, but I don't think it discusses adding methods to objects that already exists.

Comment: Seems like testing that would be easy enough. Modify their example so that the function is added later.

Comment: You can't add the function because you can't declare the function to begin with. Try typing the function in the console. You get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here".